# Volkswagen driverside outer C/V boot leaking can it cause other issues?

Tags: vw, passat, cv-boot, cv-axle

Took a recently purchased used vehicle to a VW dealership for a checkup/ oil change

One of the things they found is a leaking outer C/V boot (driver side front tire)

They didn't seem to think repair was urgent, but due to an aftermarket axle, they said they need a new axle to address the leaking boot.

My question is can this problem cause other problems? I've never even heard of a C/V boot before yesterday. I want to know if this is a repair I should rush or something I can put off for a few weeks or months?

Comment: What is the year/model/engine/transmission of your VW?

Comment: @Paulster2 it is a 2002 pasat wagen automatic transmission v6 engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read that a CV joint can take a while to fail but when it does you can lose control or the axle can spin about and break some nearby parts that get caught in the chaos. A leaking CV joint basically succumbs to corrosion as water infiltrates into places it shouldn't be. Outer CV joints will eventually begin to give a terrible click/click/click sound as you make sharp turns.

Here's a straightforward symptoms link
https://www.raxles.com/axleparts.aspx

This is a good discussion in this area too [Can My Wheel Fall Off From a Bad CV Joint?](https://youtu.be/JwOvFZd2WEs)

And then here's a Volkswagon specific video where this fella comments on a situation where the need for an OEM genuine part Volkswagon axle was called for to avoid driveline vibrations that you can get with aftermarket parts [2003 Jetta Vibration Diagnosis- Is it Driveline, Clutch, or other?](https://youtu.be/RKcgPnJtHL4?t=97)

Answer (score 6):

If the boot is leaking, then it is the grease coming out and a lack of lubrication will cause the cv joint to fail.

Depending on the design then it may be possible to fit a new outer cv joint or it may be a complete shaft.

As for how long, that is the length of a piece of string type question...

Comment: Not sure how bad the boot is, but a torn boot will also allow dirt and road grit to get into the bearing, making it fail even quicker.